# Missing ocamlrun after having installed Ocaml

Tags: installation, ocaml, ubuntu-20.04

I am on Ubuntu 20 and Ocaml already correctly worked on my OS.

Even after

```
sudo apt remove ocaml
sudo apt autoremove ocaml
sudo apt purge ocaml
sudo apt autoremove --purge ocaml
```

installing Ocaml with `sudo apt install ocaml` (after update and upgrade) and typing eg `ocaml --help` result in:

```
bash: /usr/bin/ocaml: /usr/bin/ocamlrun: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

And it is true that /usr/bin/ contains no ocamlrun file or folder.

KR
Zlotz

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but as a side note you should install OCaml through opam, it's way easier: http://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html

Comment: What does `which ocamlrun` say?

Comment: I've installed with Opam since then, and am currently fighting to install packages with Opam and use them to run the make of a git cloned Ocaml project

Comment: It says nothing.

Comment: Did opam install an OCaml compiler? If so it should be pretty straight-forward. If not, just run `opam init` and it should install one. Make sure that everything related to OCaml that has been installed through apt has been removed

Comment: I did so, thanks. The problem is now elsewhere (it would have been easier if the direct installation worked) and could be the subject of another post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222271/discussion-between-lhooq-and-zlotz).